# Wine apps single machine with LDAP users

Tags: 20.04, wine

I've looked for answers to help me with a task and the two responses found are from 2010 and 2016 ie 'out of date' - I will try either route if all else fails.

---

TL;DR I have a set of machines (20.04.5 LTS) where users authenticate via LDAP. Only one user can ever be logged in at a time (obviously multiple people can ssh, but I mean only one graphical user session at a time).

I'm trying to build a repeatable, and reliable way to have 'machine global' Wine 7 Apps (that is to say the app data is stored local to the machine and not shared across machines). This mainly to facilitate a 'complete' out the box usable system image which can rebuild / provision more machines etc.

I know wine uses the user profile, and also uses WINEPREFIX but I've not had much success finding a reliable way to have the apps stored globally such that any authenticated LDAP user can log in and 'just have the app installed'..

---

As only one use can log in at a time I do not have the issue of overwriting files as someone else is using them, and for most cases the software is to equipment control stuff, so 99.9% of any 'user settings' would be the the same for anyone wanting to use it.

I suppose my question is: in 2022 is there defined way of doing this or any new tools created to facilitate this since 2016?

I heard mention of overlayfs as a solution but no idea if that would work, is there a way to package a wine app into the likes of a snap such that a machine wide copy of it could be pointed to and any use then start it (the apps only need tcp/ip stuff to send machine commands).

Sorry its a bit open ended...

If the solutions from 2010/16 are still the 'only' way to do it, sobeit, its more asking if things have improved since then.

Owen.

Comment: Did you try the old solutions? If they are not working, share the issue with the solutions you found. It looks like you found solutions and don't want to use them just because they are old.

Comment: so TL;dr is you are correct... I realised after posting that this sort of question may not be the 'kind' best suited to AskUbuntu.... so yes @megubyte 's answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1603/wine-users-configuration does still work (symlink the ~/.wine/drive_c/ folder).    Hope you can appreciate that after seeing a 12yr old answer I was sceptical of its relevance (I bet 99.9% of 12yr old answers don't work on new OSes) so I asked this question on the half basis that something more suitable may have arisen that is deemed 'better' / the now right way. So I do apologise